# How to track which resource is utilised by each customer in SimPY

Tags: python, simpy

In the official SimPY documentation [here](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/monitoring.html#resource-usage) under the 'Resource usage' section, there is an example on how we can monitor the usage of resources. However, is there a way to track the number of times each resource was utilized? For example, I will let to know how many customers utilize Counter 1, how many customers utilize Counter 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, resources do not have identity.  You need to create your own resource objects that can track their usage and use a store instead of a resource